# iPhone - What is the best way to display error message below UITextfield

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a form with many UITextfields like Name, password, email, etc.., and during validation, i want to display the error message for the fields below the respective textfield.

What is the best way to do this. Any examples would really help.

Comment: No wonder your name is "Flash Thunder"....

Comment: put a label under the textfield and display error there. Wrap label and textfield into a single custom control for cleaner code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new object model containing a textfield, a label and a validation block.
When the textfield resigns first responder, call the block to check if it is valid and if not, display the label

Something like this

```
@protocol ValidationTextFieldDelegate

-(void) validationTextField:(ValidationTextField*)textField didResignWithResult:(BOOL)result;

@end

@interface ValidationTextField : NSObject <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *errorLabel;
@property (copy) void(^validationBlock)(BOOL);
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ValidationTextFieldDelegate> delegate;

@end

@implementation ValidationTextField

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField*)textField {
    BOOL result = self.validationBlock();

    self.errorLabel.hidden = result;

    if (self.delegate) {
        [self.delegate validationTextField:self didResignWithResult:result];
    }
}
```

And in your controller

```
-(void) validationTextField:(ValidationTextField*)textField didResignWithResult:(BOOL)result {
    if (!result) {
        int yOffset = textField.errorLabel.bounds.size.height;

        // Update here the frames of your other textfields, adding the yOffset to their frames
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My doubt is how will the remaining below text fields align based on the new label added. I want the errorLabel to be initally hidden and show up once the form is submitted.

Comment: You've got two solutions : either always leave an empty space below each textfield or update your view after a textfield has resigned

Comment: Is there any implementation that I could refer.

Comment: Just updated my code to show you the logic

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have one more doubt. Is it possible to design the Textfields using xib if i use the above ValidationTextField class. If so,how can i do it.

Comment: You should be able to do so but I have a doubt as how to link them with your properties... As you only have one textfield and one label you could do easily do it programmatically. And if you make your ValidationTxtField class inherit from UIView you will be able to create the xib for your controller and lay them out for your form