# how to show textfield validation error message in a label

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am a beginner in iOS programming. I am creating a registration form, and doing client side validation on the textfield. What I want is to display the error message below the textfield in a label. I searched alot and get [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510460/iphone-what-is-the-best-way-to-display-error-message-below-uitextfield) but I am finding it difficult to understand and I think there must be a simpler way to achieve this. I am able to show the message in a label, but the problem is it doesn't hide when the focus is set to that textfield again.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField == _emailTextField)
    {
        if(![self validateEmailWithString:_emailTextField.text])
        {
            //showing error on a label
            [_errorMessageLabel setText:@"please enter valid Email"];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //valid email
    }
}

- (bool)validateEmailWithString:(NSString *)emailStr
{
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailStr];
}
```

Comment: I think I don't understand the question. Just clear the label when the text field becomes the first responder? Examine text field delegate methods further, you have a callback when the text field has focus.

Comment: r u saying this [textField resignFirstResponder]; self.errorMessageLabel.text = @"";

Comment: No, check Bhanu Priya's answer

Comment: To be specific, i want to work the label like an alert view. After error message on label, when we tap again on the textfield, label should be clear.

Comment: I have a query, this code with the answer working fine for a single texfield. What if i have a 10-15 textfield on a form. Is this a optimized way to show validation error message?

Comment: @KunalKumar Yes its fine for 10-15 textfield and as much as you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a simple solution. Just hide your label when focus is set to `UITextField` in below delegate method

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    _errorMessageLabel.hidden = YES;

    ...

}
```

Comment: it is hiding the label forever, not showing the label when wrong input entered in the textfield.

Comment: Thanks its working great. Such a simple code for showing validation error message :)

Comment: @KunalKumar, when wrong input entered in the textfield, before setting text to label, again show it means set _errorMessageLabel.hidden = NO;

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong, what you only want is to hide the text (meaning empty text) or hide the label itself?

To hide text, use "textFieldDidBeginEditing" to empty your label

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [_errorMessageLabel setText:@""];
}
```

To hide the label,

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    _errorMessageLabel.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: either will work for me, let me check your solution.

Comment: its working, but bhanu replied first so i am going to accept his answer. +1